# How to calculate total time in hour using DAX?

Tags: time, powerbi, dax

I have to table, start and end with time as the data, I want to calculate the total hour from start to end.

I tried this but it does not return hour, it returns date and the date also same in the column:

```
Column = SUM('Data'[Finish Date])-SUM('Data'[Start Date])*24-12
```

Anyone can give me idea please. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datediff-function-dax

```
Column = DATEDIFF('Data'[Start Date], 'Data'[Finish Date], HOUR)
```

Comment: Not what you've been looking for?